# Star / Magic Particles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles, effects

I'm doing something for Christmas and I would love to add a stars/lights/magic trail to Santa Claus.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-6cggDxzBk

[image]

How can I do that? I will render using Cycles.

Thank you!

Comment: Particles with an emission as material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a curve, create an object that will be your emitter (here icosphere) and another one that will be your particle:

[image]

Make the object follow the curve with a *Follow Path* constraint, give it a particle system > *Emitter*, under *Emission* choose the number of particles that will be emitted, the start and end frame, their lifetime, under *Velocity* decrease the *Normal* value so that the particle will be slow, choose the other object as particle under *Render > Render As*, deactivate *Show Emitter* to make invisible (you can also deactivate it under *Viewport Display*):

[image]

In the Scene panel, disable the *Gravity* or low it down a lot, give an emission material to your particle, enable the *Bloom* effect (or *Glare* in the *Compositor*), play:

[image]